# Need Help Overloading Construct in C#

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

I'm new to c# and I'm trying to overload yourCar into the Car class where it will be instantiated and then later displayed back in the main. 
The problem I keep having trouble with is making sure I'm overloading it because the default values keep remaining instead of the new price coupled with the default color.

```
// Creates a Car class
// You can construct a Car using a price and color
// or just a price, in which case a Car is black
// or no parameters, in which case a Car is $10,000 and black
using static System.Console;
class DebugNine3
{
   static void Main()
   {
      Car myCar = new Car(32000, "red");
      Car yourCar = new Car(14000);
      Car theirCar = new Car();
      WriteLine("My {0} car cost {1}", myCar.Color,
         myCar.Price.ToString("c2"));
      WriteLine("Your {0} car cost {1}",
         yourCar.Color, yourCar.Price.ToString("c2"));
      WriteLine("Their {0} car cost {1}",
         theirCar.Color, theirCar.Price.ToString("c2"));
  }
}

class Car
{
  // private string color;
  // private int price;
  // 
  public string color;
  public int price;

   //DEfault no values entered
   public Car() : this(10000, "black")
   {

   //One value entered
   public Car(int price) : this()
   {
   }

   //both values entered
   public Car(int price, string color)
   {

       Price = price;
       Color = color;
   }

   //what it does with the values passed to it 
   public string Color
   {
      get
      {
         return color;
      }
      set
      {
         color = value;
      }
   }

   public int Price
   {
      get
      {
         return price;
      }
      set
      {
         price = value;
      }
   }
}
```

The results I getting are:
My red car cost $32,000.00
Your black car cost $10,000.00
Their black car cost $10,000

Comment: Please edit your question to show what results you are getting?

Comment: My results are: My red car cast $32,000.00; Your black car cost $10,000.00; Their black car cost $10,000

Comment: Note that backing fields should not be public

Comment: So what would be a better way to call the part  the of the default value I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting anything. Your `public Car(int price)` constructor does nothing with price, do this instead:

```
public Car(int price) : this()
{
    this.Price = price;
}
```

This way, default constructor will fire (and set default price & color), then you set the proper, new one.

**Edit**
Additionally, the better way to set default parameters is via parametrs themselves instead of calling this with default values. See example:

```
class Test {
  public int A {get; set;} = 5;
  public string B {get; set;} = "test";

  public Test() {
  }

  public Test(int a) {
    this.A = a;
  }

  public Test(int a, string b) {
    this.A = a;
    this.B = b;
  }
}
```